# Show post like this image in my newssite

Tags: php, wp-query, query

I want to know how to query like this photo in my newssite for a category.
See this image and help by give the query code.

[image]

Do I use Offset or if else. How to query for this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're asking for. If you need a simple query for a category. try [generatewp.com](https://generatewp.com/) for the fastest solution.

Here's how to code it yourself. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query you'll want to use the **Category_Parameters**

Comment: i want first post of this category come with big image , then come 4 post with only title like: given photo left side  , then come more 6 post of this cat after 5 post which allrady show in left side , now 6 post come with a feture image and title , see give photo right side . now how i query this in my wp theme code

Comment: then you're talking about layout. using conditional if/else. you should update your question with more detail. but i think sticky posts are what you're talking about. https://codex.wordpress.org/Sticky_Posts